# assembly and state variable

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to use the name of the local variable of contract with sload code ?

```
contract Test {
  int a=999;
  function doIt() {
    assembly {
    sload(a);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although you may want to store the result of this load in a memory variable:

```
contract Test {
    int a = 999; // That's storage
    function doIt() {
        int b; // That's memory
        assembly {
            b := sload(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let b := sload(a)  
This will use stack instead of memory.
Only drawback is that the variable can only be used inside the assembly block.